# Setting callback for SEditableText widget to save text

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have implemented an SEditableText widget in my editor plugin but I can't figure out a reasonable way of accessing the value in the widget. I know there is an SEditableText.OnTextChanged() function but I don't see anyway to override it or set a callback of my own. Is there a standard way to save the content of an SEditableText to a variable?

I am working in the context of FModeToolKit, not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate the slate widget, you should already be making a call to `SNew`. As part of the property initialiser chain list, initialise `SEditableText::OnTextChanged` and bind to your container UObject, using `BIND_UOBJECT_DELEGATE`. The delegate signature should be `FOnTextChanged`. Your handler will receive an `FText` which may be stored in a variable as required.

Example:

```
SEditableText EditableText = SNew(SEditableText)
   .OnTextChanged(BIND_UOBJECT_DELEGATE(FOnTextChanged, OnTextChanged);
```

then:

```
void UMyUObject::HandleOnTextChanged(const FText& InText)
{
   // Do something with text
}
```

Take a look at it in action in `UEditableText::RebuildWidget` (EditableText.cpp:50, v4.22.1).

NB. I know you specifically asked about `OnTextChanged`, but also consider  `OnTextComitted`; this is only fired when the slate widget loses focus.

Ah; `BIND_UOBJECT_DELEGATE` is in UMG. The macro is however just a helper to create a UObject to which you may bind:

```
#define BIND_UOBJECT_DELEGATE(Type, Function) \
Type::CreateUObject( this, &ThisClass::Function )
```

So there's two options, either use `<my type>::CreateUObject`, or you could bind via a shared pointer. Off the top of my head, SP method should look *something* like:

---

**Edit** (based on comments): 
If you're not linked against UMG, you could try manually creating the UObject based on the macro defined in SlateWrapperTypes in UMG:

```
   #define BIND_UOBJECT_DELEGATE(Type, Function) \
    Type::CreateUObject( this, &ThisClass::Function )
```

To instead use a shared pointer, the syntax should be along the following lines:

```
 auto OnTextChangedSP = FOnTextChanged::CreateSP(this, &MyClass::MyOnTextChangedHandler);
 SEditableText EditableText = SNew(SEditableText)
     .OnTextChanged(OnTextChangedSP);
```

Comment: Thanks this helps and I think I get how it's supposed to work now. I'm working in the context of FModeToolKit and BIND_UOBJECT_DELEGATE is not declared. Is there something I need to do to access the UObject from an editor toolkit?

Comment: Ah; `BIND_UOBJECT_DELEGATE` is in UMG. The macro is however just a helper to create a UObject to which you may bind:

    #define BIND_UOBJECT_DELEGATE(Type, Function) \
 Type::CreateUObject( this, &ThisClass::Function )

So there's two options, either use `<my type>::CreateUObject`, or you could bind via a shared pointer. Off the top of my head, SP method should look _something_ like:

     auto OnTextChangedSP = FOnTextChanged::CreateSP(this, &MyClass::MyOnTextChangedHandler);
     SEditableText EditableText = SNew(SEditableText)
       .OnTextChanged(OnTextChangedSP);

Comment: Sorry that didn't come out well in comments at all. I've updated my answer to incorporate your questions!